# Display chm help for UDF in a separate window from function wizard in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, chm

I created UDF functions and chm help for them, hooked up chm help with functions through VBA like this:

```
Application.MacroOptions macro:="MyMacroName", _
  Description:="Description", _
  Category:="Company", HelpContextID:=100, _
  HelpFile:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyUDFs.chm"
```

When I look through my UDF in function wizard, click "Help on this function", my chm pops up in Excel 2007.

However, in Excel 2003, chm help is displayed inside Excel Help. Looks like it is automatically integrated into Excel 2003 help. I still want my chm file display in a separate window like it does in Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer, unfortunately it's NO.
See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/bda100fb-070b-42ed-b846-90e5488ab2dd/